# R and keras: Concatenate branches

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a **two branch model**. The first branch consists of two LSTMs that processes *sequential data*. However, I want to keep the batch size as well as the number of lookbacks (2nd input dimension) **variable**. Therefore:

```
library(keras)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

n_features_sequential <- 5
n_features_static <- 3
sequential_data <- layer_input(batch_shape = list(NULL, NULL, n_features_sequential))
```

I want the model to output a prediction **for each timestep** - also the intermediate. That means that during the training I also provide the model with a label for each lookback. So for example if my input has the shape `(1, 5, 5)` my labels would have `(1, 5)`. This can be done via the `return_sequences=TRUE`. All in all, my recurrent branch looks like this:

```
lstm_output <- sequential_data %>% 
  layer_lstm(units = 256, return_sequences = TRUE, dropout = 0.25, recurrent_dropout = 0.35) %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 256, return_sequences = TRUE, dropout = 0.25, recurrent_dropout = 0.35) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu")
```

Here comes the tricky part for me. The second branch handles **static features**, that should be concatenated to the output of the lstm before further processing. First I pass the static input through a dense layer like this

```
static_data <- layer_input(batch_shape = list(NULL, n_features_static))
dense_output <- static_data %>%
  layer_dense(units = 32)
```

This produces an output of `(batch, 32)`. However, the lstm unit outputs a *three dimensional vector*, so I want the output of the static branch to be concatenated to every timestep results from the recurrent unit. I could use `keras::k_repeat(n = ??)` , however, the second dimension of the lstm output is kept variable so I can set the `n` parameter here.

My further model looks like this:

```
preds <- list(lstm_output, dense_output) %>%
  keras::layer_concatenate(axis = -1) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 128) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

When the second dimension of sequential_data  is 5, then preds should have the dimension (batch, 5) as well.

Any ideas to achieve this without providing a `static_data`  vector that already has three dimension.